# Set of Base class together with inherited classes

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

In this code snippet below, there is a class of Pets, with inherited classes Cat and Dog. I'd like to have a set of all of my pets.

```
    class Pet{
    //
};

class Dog: Pet{
    //
};
class Cat: Pet{
    //
};

int main(
        set<Pet> a;

        set<Pet*> b;
)
```

Obviously if I use option b, any of the pointers, dog or cat, can be in the set, but I'm not sure how I could make a copy of the set.

Similarly, if I make a copy of set a, would the copy constructors of Cat,Dog be called for items of their respective types?

Comment: please dont post fantasy code. This wont compile before you even reach the declaration of the sets and I have the feeling that you want public inheritance not private, dont you?

Answer (score 0):

In the set `a` you can store only `Pet`s, no `Cat`s or `Dog`s. The copy constructor question is thus irrelevant.

With the set `b`, you can copy it naturally, but the copy would contain pointers to the same objects. More to this, you'll also need to store those objects somewhere.

What you probably wanted is `set<unique_ptr<Pet>>`. You won't be able to copy it.

If you really want to copy polymorphic objects, check the [clone idiom](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/18757/).